# Frosted glass effect over dyanmic video

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a media control bar for a video player with the controls blurring the background. Currently I can get the glassy look but I can't get blurring to work. 
I tried following this guide: https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/how-to-do-css-only-frosted-glass-effect-e2666bafab91 but it seems like it only works on static images.

Here's an example of what I want: [image]

I also saw the webkit backdrop-filter which looks perfect but it's only stable on safari so I can't use that. Any advice for frosted glass on dynamic videos?

Comment: I did some research on this same thing, and concluded it's practically impossible. All frosted glass demos use a reference image to blur. We have to wait for backdrop-filter to become supported. I'd love it if anyone can prove me wrong.

Comment: Yeah I've spent a couple hours looking and trying to put variations on the static solutions. It's surprising though, it feels pretty common

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this by copying the bottom part of the video to a `canvas` every frame and blurring the `canvas` via CSS. It seems to work well in Chrome, but flashes sometimes in Firefox. Doing the blur programmatically in the `canvas` with something like [Superfast Blur](http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html) might be more performant, but that's an experiment for another day. Tomorrow, probably.

```js
function initControls (player, blurRadius, controlHeight, videoWidth, videoHeight) {
  // crop player to video size
  let video = player.querySelector('video');
  videoWidth = videoWidth || video.clientWidth;
  videoHeight = videoHeight || video.clientHeight;
  player.style.width = videoWidth + 'px';
  player.style.height = videoHeight + 'px';

  // crop control bar to video size
  let controlBar = player.querySelector('.control-bar');
  controlBar.style.width = videoWidth + 'px';
  controlBar.style.height = controlHeight + 'px';

  // canvas needs to be slightly taller than what gets displayed
  // to blur cleanly
  let canvas = player.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = videoWidth;
  canvas.height = 2 * blurRadius + controlHeight;
  canvas.style.filter = `blur(${blurRadius}px)`;
  canvas.style.top = -2 * blurRadius + 'px';

  // copy video to canvas
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let videoCropY = videoHeight - canvas.height;
  function updateCanvas () {
    ctx.drawImage(
      video,
      0, videoCropY, canvas.width, canvas.height,
      0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height
    );
  }

  // update the canvas only when necessary
  let hovering = false;
  function renderLoop () {
    updateCanvas();
    if (hovering && !video.paused) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
    }
  }
  
  // no point in rendering to a canvas you can't see
  player.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    hovering = true;
    renderLoop();
  });
  player.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => { hovering = false; });
  video.addEventListener('play', renderLoop);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  // do the magic
  initControls(document.querySelector('.player'), 4, 50, 320, 240);

  // basic play button functionality
  document.querySelector('.play-button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  let v = event.target.closest('.player').querySelector('video');
    if (v.ended) v.currentTime = 0;
    if (v.paused) {
      v.play();
    } else {
      v.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* styling required for blurred control background */
.player {
  position: relative;
}
.player > video {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
.control-bar > canvas {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.control-bar {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* height of control bar is specified in javascript, sorry about that */
}

/* simple control-hiding mechanism; other methods also work */
/* javascript relies on mouseover and mouseout to decide whether to update canvas */
.player > .control-bar {
  display: none;
}
.player:hover > .control-bar {
  display: block;
}

/* styling actual controls; adjust to taste */
.play-button {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <video src="https://archive.org/download/MedicalA1950/MedicalA1950_512kb.mp4"></video>
  <div class="control-bar">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div class="play-button">PLAY/PAUSE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```